# nslookup and host(linux) shows 2 ip's for some computers but not all

Tags: ftp, ip-address, nslookup

My company has an FTP server. Outside of our network, it works fine. Inside of our local network some computers work fine and others don't. The ones that don't will often time out or be just ridiculously slow. I started trying to dig a little and found that on the machines that work nslookup shows one ip address. On the machines that are having issues, nslookup and host (I have a linux box in front of me) show two ip's. The problem computers can't ping the domain, or one of the ip's but the other ip pings fine. I am not sure what would cause that but I hoping that someone here could give me a clue so that I can relay it to our IT guy (he doesn't know the answer, we have discussed it ad nauseam).

Comment: What operating system is on those faulty computers? Have you checked forward and reverse entries in the DNS-servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they have a wireless and wired network adapter and the wireless network they are connected to does not have a search path for the ftp.  It could be many things.  What are you running nslookup on, the ftp servers hostname/ip or the problematic computer?  Can you post the output you are getting from these commands?

Comment: Well to make it stranger, at the moment it is now reporting one ip and everything is working but it seems to go in and out. The result earlier was Name: ftp.westmarkind.com Addresses: 50.43.103.0, 50.43.103.67

Comment: Oh and I am running nslookup from the problem computers.

Comment: You are running nslookup on the faulty computers like this: nslookup ftp.westmarkind.com ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Oh and some are wired and some are wireless.

Comment: I am going to mark this one as answered. I appreciate your help. My IT guy just said that he was thumbing around in the server settings and found two ip addresses and deleted to the one with the ending octet of 0. That is why I am no longer getting two ip's. It is still weird that not everyone was seeing both but hopefully that resolves our ftp woes. Thanks for you time.